# Decompling an android apk

Tags: java, android

I am trying to Decompling an android apk with using apktool, dex2jar and jd-GUI. Its working smooth and I am getting 98% result in even java code. I have one issue is I am getting digit instead of character in some place like below.

```
setContentView(2130968603);
```

as well

```
this.v.findViewById(2131689676).setBackgroundResource(2131623996);
```

How can I know which text I should replace with this numbers ?

Thanks

Comment: may if you are able to decompile R.java you will find these references there

Comment: I think they are resource ID's. Find R.java, maybe under resource directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `apktool` for decompiling with resources

https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/

Answer (score 0):

the advice to use the apktool  is a right one. 
You may use apktool online as well: http://www.javadecompilers.com/apktool